# How to add existing Xcode project to git version control in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, git, github, ios8, xcode6

It's clear how to add an existing project to GitHub outside of Xcode, there are a number of tutorial: https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/

There are also a number of tutorial of how to create a new project in Xcode under version control.

However, there are no tutorial on how to do both: add an existing project with the controls within Xcode. Is this even possible? Or since I already started the project, I'll have to do it all via command line?

Comment: Didn't really want to open terminal every time I needed to add/commit/push, was hoping I could set things up in Xcode.

Comment: I didn't say you had to open terminal every time you need to add/commit/push. Why do you assume that? It isn't what your question is about. You asked how to get this thing under `git` control. The answer is, you didn't do it when you created the project, so use the command line. Just do it and move on.

Comment: Don't forget to enable Source Control in Xcode itself.

Comment: matt u mad bro? he didn't want to use command line, if you have answers to that do it and move on.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Since you didn't ask Xcode for a local git repository inside this project folder when you created the project, you will have to create one via the command line.

After that, you can use Xcode's internal GUI to give git commands in your project - if that's the kind of thing you really want to do (personally I abhor Xcode's git interface).